# Laravel Task schedule with python script "Exit Code: 127(Command not found)"

Tags: php, python, laravel, ubuntu

I'm using laravel 5.8 and I created a console command to call a python script (the python module is [PyVantagePro](https://github.com/LionelDarras/PyVantagePro));

The command works fine if I run it in console, but when I set up the crontab to automatically run the script I get the error "Exit Code: 127(Command not found)"

Full error log:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The command "pyvantagepro getarchives tcp:5.175.66.169:9002 --start "2019-05-19 07:00" --output /var/www/laravel/storage/stations_data/update_archive_6.csv" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /var/www/laravel

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sh: 1: pyvantagepro: not found
 in /var/www/laravel/app/Console/Commands/getReadings.php:78
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\getReadings->handle()
#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#5 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#6 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#7 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#8 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(908): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(269): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\getReadings), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/laravel/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Are you able to see the command in `php artisan list`?

Comment: Yes, the command works fine using php artisan command:name. The problem happens when the command is executed by the cron

Comment: Any log, that hints some issue?

Comment: added the full log to the question

Comment: what us in getReadings.php: line 78?

Comment: if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                $log->status = 1;
                $log->log = new ProcessFailedException($process);
            }
The line 78 is: 
$log->log = new ProcessFailedException($process); 
To log the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194332/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is neither PHP nor Python related but likely the "culprit" is `$PATH` environmental variable whuch is different for either cron run or cron user (if different). The common workaround is to set full path to the binary you want to execute (so instead of `foo` you invoke i.e. `/usr/bin/foo`) or to ensure `$PATH` used by the cron is set the expected values, pointing to all the locations you want to be searched for invoked binaries. This can be done globally per crontab, by simply adding:

```
PATH=<value-for-PATH-variable>
```

to top of your crontab file. To ensure it matches the value you have when running tools from command line simply do

```
echo $PATH
```

when in shell and either copy what you have there to your crontab, or copy only these segments (paths) that are related to the `pyvantagepro` tool that are failing currently (recommended approach).

Comment: Yeahp this worked added my echo $PATH to the crontab and solved the problem. Thanks